# Show that if $f(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ then $f^{-1}$ is not continuous (Is my proof right?)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $S^1= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=1\}$ and $f:[0, 2\pi) \rightarrow S^1$ defined as

$f(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$

Show that its inverse $f^{-1}: S^1 \rightarrow [0, 2\pi)$ is not continuous.

---

**My attempt**

It will be enough to prove that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous in $(1,0) \in S^1$.

First note that if $(x,y) \in S^1$ is such that $y<0$ then $ t = f^{-1}(x,y) \in [\pi, 2 \pi)$. Let $\delta >0$ and $(x,y) \in S^1$ such that $\lVert (x,y) - (1,0) \rVert < \delta$, then $y \in (-\delta, \delta)$. In particular if $y<0$ then $\pi \leq f^{-1}(x,y) \leq 2 \pi$. So for each $\delta >0$ there exists $(x,y) \in S^1$ such that $\lVert (x,y) - (1,0) \rVert < \delta$, but $|f^{-1}(x,y) - f^{-1}(1,0)| = f^{-1}(x,y) \geq \pi$. Therefore $f^{-1}$ is not continuous in $(1,0)$.

I just want to know if my proof is right, or if it can be improved

Comment: Yes it is OK. Note that more generally, no surjection from $S^1$ onto $[0,2\pi)$ can be continuous because the latter is not compact. Also, $S^1$ cannot be homeomorphic to an interval because that interval deprived of its midpoint is not connected, contrarily to $S^1$ deprived of any point.

Comment: Thanks! When you say that $[0, 2 \pi)$ is not compact, do you mean compact with respect to $\mathbb{R}$ or compact with respect to itself?

Comment: [Compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Open_cover_definition) is an [intrisic property of topological spaces.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property) Here, $[0,2\pi)$ is equipped with the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) of the usual topology on $\Bbb R.$ But by [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem), a subspace of $\Bbb R$ is a compact space iff it is a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R.$